# How to mix DHCP-provided DNS servers with statically written DNS servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

I am trying to make a combination of the DNS servers provided by my ISP and 3 static (8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1 and 9.9.9.9).

On Ubuntu 18.04, I did it by adding the static DNS to "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail" and running "resolvconf -u".

On CentOS 6, I did it with dhclient options "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf" by adding "append domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 9.9.9.9".

In both cases it adds them after the DHCP-provided ones as I want and dig +trace confirms that it is using the DHCP-given DNS server for now(as its up, supposedly if its down it will move to next one and so on).

Question is: How to do the same thing on CentOS 9/AlmaLinux 9/RockyLinux 9?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the NetworkManager `nmcli` or systemd-resolved (Add the DNS option under the [Resolve] section